# CSS1 Sprite animation on mouse hover?

Tags: css, animation, hover, mouse, sprite

I know if I hover my mouse over a CSS1 Sprite it will switch to the hover image, but is there a way to get it to load more images sequentially on mouse hover, like an animation? Please, no CSS3 responses, CSS3 animation isn't supported fully by all browsers. Thanx

Comment: The `:hover` selector is in CSS 2.1 and [supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=hover) back to IE8... How much further do you need?

Comment: I need IE7 probably, IE6 just won't work. However ExtPro's answer gave me a clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to use the newer CSS3 techniques, this is not possible without resorting to Javascript, or using an animated GIF for the hover image.